# ipad - splitview

Tags: ipad

I'm very much interested in creating a app very similar to the Settings in ipad [split view in both the orientations]. I want to this programmatically without using ib. 
Also, the app which i am trying to create will be a subview of a main application and would be available on the click of a button.

I'm tyring hard on this. How ever no success yet :)

Any help on this would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by 
"app which i am trying to create will be a subview of a main application and would be available on the click of a button"

But this is how you can create a uisplitviewcontroller programmatically:

1) Initialize your uisplitviewcontroller

```
UISplitViewController *splitviewcontroller = [UISplitViewController alloc] init];
```

2) Create master and detail uiviewcontrollers

```
UIViewController *masterViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UIViewController *detailViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

3) Create 2 navigation controllers, 1 for the master and one for the detail views (optional)

```
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease]; 
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];
```

4) Add the nav controllers to the splitviewcontroller (or just the viewcontrollers, if you opted not use the nav controllers)

```
splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil]
```

5) Add your uisplitviewcontroller... 
Let's say you want to display it modally at the click of a button

```
[myCurrentViewController presentModalViewController:splitViewController animated:YES];
```

Be sure to read up on the delegation pattern for any communications needed between the master/detail views